# At what rate did the Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles age?

Tags: teenage-mutant-ninja-turtles

I don't know if there is any canon that can answer this, but I was talking with my brother, and got to wondering...

Once the TMNTs were "humanified", did they age at a rate that was closer to a human rate of aging, or did they continue to age at a more "turtle" rate?

Comment: Either way, They can't stay *teenage* forever. I guess "Twenty-Something Mutant Ninja Turtles" just doesn't have the same ring to it. ;)

Comment: Hmm, that's a possibility I hadn't considered... I mean, Bart Simpson has been what, 10 or so for like the past 23 years! lol

Comment: @gnovice "Tweenage" Mutant Ninja Turtles? <edit> of course being a tween would them younger. all well.

Comment: Midlife-Crisis Ninja Turtles, Heroes in a Half Shell...errr, Ferrari!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the [Mirage Comics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teenage_Mutant_Ninja_Turtles_%28Mirage_Studios%29) the Turtles were teens in the 80s.  The series has had time skips and jumps (as most comics do) but the Turtles have aged based on that.

The Turtles count their age in years like humans do, and they seem to mature similarly to humans (though some might argue that different humans mature at different times).  This may be psychological, though, as their psychology seems relatively consistant with that of a human as opposed to physiological.

There is no information as to their lifespan - even they themselves may not know until they start dropping dead from age-related illness (though, given that they are ninja, they most likely will not live that long).  Warriors typically die by the sword, after all.

Comment: Since snapping turtles pop up occasionally with Civil War musket balls lodged in their shells, and a Galapagos Tortoise that was around when Darwin visited the islands recently died, it is likely that some varieties of turtles age very slowly.

Comment: The original series was very explicit about their aging relative to real time; the entire conceit of No 11 was built around the need to catch up the narrative universe with the publication timeline, which had fallen months behind.

Answer (score -2):

I am not familiar with the ages of their human friends but Casey was at least 22 when he left for Colorado so his daughter being around 15 the turtles are probably 37 so why is it still called TMNT when they are almost old enough to be grandparents.

Comment: You appear to have a hint of an answer to how they age here but it isn't very explicit and you end with your own question that might or might not be rhetorical. If you are answering the question here could you [edit] this to be more focused on it and add in some evidence to back up your claims. If, however, this is a new question you should ask it as one!